# Можно с помощью метода jQuery изменять размеры окна браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно с помощью метода jQuery изменять размеры окна браузера? Не могу найти такой метод, он существует?

Comment: ......нельзя.......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну не то чтобы совсем нельзя, но в общем случае нельзя :)

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения размеров окна есть две функции: [resizeTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) и [resizeBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeBy).

В первой задается точный размер, во второй - на сколько надо увеличить/уменьшить.

Однако, эти функции имеют следующие ограничения:

- Нельзя изменять размеры окна или таба, которые не были созданы с помощью [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).
- Нельзя изменять размеры окна или таба, когда они расположены в окне с несколькими табами.

Comment: не думаю, что речь шла именно про `window.open`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не важно, важно, что функции есть, просто у них есть ограничения по применению :)

Comment: да ну бред же. "-Доктор, у меня рак, его можно вылечить?", "-Да! Но у другого человека, у вас уже последняя стадия"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский именно! если бы он обратился раньше - то можно было бы :-) вроде до 7 версии FF :)

Comment: ..\*facepalm*..